# MFC extension libraries (GUI/Controls) recommendations

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, components

We're developing/supporting 2 large MFC applications, using VS 2005. Currently, we are looking at various MFC GUI/controls component libraries:

- www.bcgsoft.com : "BCGControlBar Pro"
- www.codejock.com : "Toolkit Pro"
- www.prof-uis.com : "Prof-UIS"
- others?

The samples/demos provided for those look all great, and the feature sets seem to match more or less between those libraries.

- Has anyone used/reviewed one/more of those?
- How is the learning curve?
- Advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 2):

You could try Visual C++ 2008 [Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984556.aspx) available for Visual Studio 2008. It is official part of Visual Studio powered by BCGSoft.

From personal experience: When the need in using Property Grid control have arisen, I've tried BCGSoft solutions, but it was less convenient than using .NET PropertyGrid (through C++/CLI wrapper).

Answer (score 2):

Toolkit pro seems to be quite popular, id software and Crytek use it for example for their editors. I looked at the BCG once, and the documentation at least was quite bad; didn't have a chance to actually work with the Toolkit pro stuff, but their trial was looking nice.

Answer (score 1):

[Parts of BCG have been incorporated into MFC](http://www.bcgsoft.com/pressreleases/PR071110.pdf) in VS2008, so I assume at least Microsoft likes it.

I know one of our products use BCG, and we haven't had any major problems with it. Then again, I rarely work with UI, so I can't really share any first-hand experience.

Answer (score 0):

I used codejock's a couple of years ago.  The library was really good, simple to use, good documentation and good, fast support (they even wrote a sample for me to demonstrate what I was asking for.)

I would recommend them, although I have not tried the others you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

We're using the new MFC classes from Visual Studio 2008 in a product. Previously we were using BCGControlBar Pro, the conversion to the new MFC classes had to be done by search and replace.

One important thing that BCGControlBar Pro lacks is a resizable layout manager, for this we use a 3rd party codeproject component (which is a pain to use). Codejock has a [resizable layout manager](http://www.codejock.com/products/controls/tour_8.asp?platform=mfc).

Another interesting thing that Codejock has is XAML support. [Here](https://forum.codejock.com/forum_topics.asp?FID=150) is their development forum XAML section and (bit dated) XAMLPad like [test tool](http://forum.codejock.com/uploads/temp/20080129_130732_MarkupPad.zip). This would have saved me the time used for creating nice GDI+ gradient buttons (Codejock uses GDI+ for XAML and I had to clone the buttons from a WPF project)

The resizable layout manager and XAML support make "Toolkit Pro" from Codejock a winner in my eyes, even though I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack was included in Visual Studio 2008 SP1. It's not as powerful as BCGControlBar Pro. And it's not for Visual C++ 2005.

Microsoft will provide better official GUI libraries for its Visual C++ and Visual C# products.

I tried both Prof-UIS freeware and BCGControlBar Pro. Prof-UIS is slower than BCGControlBar Pro, but it's easier to use.

Comment: I could see obvious streaks (trailing smear
) when dragging one of its samples.

BTW, I think Prof-UIS's tutorials are better than those of BCGControlBar Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Another vendor:

http://www.prof-uis.com

Prof-UIS is an easy-to-use MFC extension library that enables you to deliver Windows applications with a professional and user-friendly interface. More than 200 thoroughly tested and documented C++ classes,